# Pyinstaller FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.xlsx' when the file in root directory although standalonescript runs fine

Tags: pandas, pyinstaller, xlsx

Pyinstaller executable not running returning this error in command prompt

```
C:\Users\user>C:\Users\user\test\dist\main\main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 504, in read_excel
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1563, in __init__
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1419, in inspect_excel_format
  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 872, in get_handle
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_1.xlsx'
[33428] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

It can't find the xlsx file although it is in the same directory as the exe.

The code itself

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import pandas as pd


`# In[2]:


df = pd.read_excel('test_1.xlsx')


# In[3]:


df.dropna(inplace=True)


# In[4]:


df.rename(columns={'Spot start time':'Start time','Spot position':'No','Spots count':'To','Spot Name':'Description','Spot duration':'Real Length','Spot ID':'Audio Desc','Spot TVCompany':'TVCompany'}, inplace=True)`
```

I tried both --onefile and --onedir option, same results

Comment: The error is self-explained, the file "test_1.xlsx" was not found. Make sure to run the command from the path `"C:\Users\user\test\dist\main\"`.